# Export env var in make file so it's available to sub make files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rule in a top level makefile.  I want to set an environment variable at this level so it's shell accessible for all sub make rules.

How is this done please?

```
get:
    for i in $(STACK_DIRS) ; do \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i} && make get ; \
    done \
```

Comment: Which variable? `make STACK_DIRS='$(STACK_DIRS)' get` should trivially fix this (provided `STACK_DIRS` does not contain any single quotes.)

Comment: a new enviroment variable. lets say foo=bar.

Comment: `export foo` right in the Makefile would do that.

Comment: could you please provide a full example?

Comment: If you have not read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html please read it. If you have read it and can't figure something out, please [edit] your question to indicate in more detail which part you are having trouble with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Makefile variable initialization and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838715/makefile-variable-initialization-and-export)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question.  I am talking about setting an environment variable in the shell. these variables seem to be make variables.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The shell command to export a variable is also `export`.

Comment: You should never use `make` to invoke a recursive invocation of make.  You should always use the variable `$(MAKE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell command to export a variable is `export`.

```
get:
    for i in $(STACK_DIRS) ; do \
        foo="bar"; export foo; cd $(CURDIR)/$${i} && make get ; \
    done
```

Though you might as well just say

```
get:
    for i in $(STACK_DIRS) ; do \
        cd $(CURDIR)/$${i} && make foo="bar" get ; \
    done
```

A much more idiomatic way to do this is to run each target separately. We create `.$i.get_done` for each `$i` like this:

```
.PHONY: get
get: $(patsubst %,.%.get_done,$(STACK_DIRS))
.%.get_done:
    cd $(CURDIR)/$* && make foo="bar" get
```

Now if `.ick.get_done` exists, it means that `get` was run in the subdirectory `ick` and if it is newer than all of its dependencies, it does not need to be remade.

Comment: I'm guessing `$(CURDIR)` is unnecessary here, but this is speculative so I didn't remove it.

Comment: You can also use GNU make's export command directly to export a makefile variable to any commands it invokes, like `export foo = bar` (not in a recipe).

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought the OP wanted at first, but they said they didn't in comments on the question. I'm guessing they want a separate value on each iteration or something like that.