# Setting environment variables from make recipe not working as exected

Tags: makefile

When trying to run a go program using a make file, the below doesn't work.
I try to set the env variable explicitly by having 1 statement to set (export), the other to run my go code where I read the env variable. This doesn't work.

```
test:
        export Sample="Help"
        go run main.go
```

The same thing as above, implemented as below in the make file works and my go code is able read the env variable.

```
test:
        Sample="Help" go run main.go
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Makefile variable initialization and export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838715/makefile-variable-initialization-and-export)

Comment: @JimB I think the problem is that the OP does not know that lines of a recipe are executed in different shells, not the relationships between make variables and environment variables. If I am right it is not a duplicate of the question you found (but it is probably a duplicate of another question).

Comment: Lines of a recipe are executed in different shells. So your `export` command has no effect at all. Join the two lines by adding `&& \ ` at the end of the first line: `export Sample="Help" && \ `. Make will consider this as a single-line recipe and pass it to a single shell. Be careful: the backslash must be the last character of the line. No trailing spaces (I had to put spaces after the backslash but its just for Markdown proper rendering).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other comments each line is run in a separate shell, so to get the result of a variable from one shell you need to "chain" them as shown in the comments.

Another way that I find quite neat for this (and avoid having to chain shell commands) is:

```
.PHONY: all
all: export TEST=123
all:
    @echo "TEST (make) = $(TEST)"
    @echo "TEST (shell) = $$TEST"
    @./script.sh


$(info TEST: $(TEST) - not set outside the recipe)
```

test script contains `echo "TEST (in shell script) = $TEST"`

Output is:

```
TEST:  - not set outside the recipe
TEST (make) = 123
TEST (shell) = 123
TEST (in shell script) = 123
```